# electric bass frets and tabs

Tags: self-learning

Hi all I'm a newbie on bassing and I'm learning tabs now

this tab

G ------------------------------------ 
D ------------------5-----------------
A --------2-5------------5----2-------
E ---3-----------------------------3--

While I start with first string and 3d fret then for A:2-5 do I hold down the A string on 2nd fret then while keeping this pressed I also push the A string on 5th fret? or do I let go of the string on 2nd fret and push 5th fret ?

cheers !

Comment: On guitar and bass, the strings are usually numbered from thin to thick. Therefore, you start with the *4th* string. Be aware that a lot of tabs give no clue as to the timing - as here. And if you know how a bass line goes, why not try to learn it by listening, and not relying on tabs? There are a lot of inaccurate tabs out there. Beware!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're playing at the fifth fret then you can take your finger off the second fret, but you don't have to.
If you were playing a piece where the music goes back to the second fret immediately, then it might make more sense to leave that finger on while you finger the fifth fret.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple G major arpeggio. Middle finger will play the 1st note (G), leaving the index to play B, and the 5th fret notes can play using pinky. Then reverse.

Once a string has another note higher than the previously played one, there's no need to leave the lower finger on. It makes no difference to the sound at all. You may, however, want to play the former note again, so if your finger span is wide enough, here, it's not a bad idea to keep index on that A string, 2nd fret.

My small hands can't manage that, so I release the B in order to reach the D on 5th fret. But keep my hand stretched, ready for the return B.

Comment: Even average to large hands can struggle with 1 finger per fret in the low register of the electric bass. I use three finger upright fingering, 1,2,4 till about the 5th fret, sometimes even higher.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - yes, the 'one finger per fret' works pretty well on guitar, but never worked for me (or students) on bass. Pinky often gets a work-out. Just another reason for playng 5 string..?

Comment: The 5 string does give  more register and fingering options but in this case just spelling out a simple G triad like this I prefer to use 2-1-shift 4-4 fingering ascending. It’s much easier on the left hand and it has the added benefit of teaching beginners how to shift positions very early on.